# How to unkeep or force remove @javax.persistence.Transient annotated methods in JPA entities in ProGuard?

Tags: jpa, annotations, proguard, shrink, negate

I'm extracting JPA entities into a separate Fat/Uber jar for external system to use.
ProGuard is used through com.github.wvengen:proguard-maven-plugin to shrink all other unused code.
I want to keep all methods in JPA entities except ones annotated by @javax.persistence.Transient annotation. I've found "!transient" for field modifiers in ProGuard rules, but seems that !@javax.persistence.Transient for methods does not work :(
Can I reach the same effect somehow for methods by other way ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately I've not got an answer on this question and was not be able to solve this by ProGuard+MavenPlugin directly, but I've resolved this problem with one additional step before run a ProGuard. I've just used ByteBuddy + Maven plugin on Maven phase before you run ProGuard Maven plugin and it will then optimize/remove the rest unused stuff, see details about byte-buddy instrumentation step here: [byte-buddy remove/strip methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66853059/how-to-remove-shrink-import-some-clazz-someclass-statement-by-means-of-byteco)